On uniform convergence of integrals with respect to a sequence of Gaussian measures
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real separable Hilbert space and let  $\mathcal{H}_n$ be a sequence of finite-dimensional subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$ with $\dim \mathcal{H}_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Write $\mu_n$ for the standard (mean 0, covariance identity) Gaussian probability measure on $\mathcal{H}_n$ and $\widetilde{\mu}_n$ for the measure on $\mathcal{H}$ which is the image of $\mu_n$ under the inclusion $  \mathcal{H}_n\hookrightarrow \mathcal{H}$.
Let $f_k$ be a sequence of uniformly bounded non-negative continuous functions on $\mathcal{H}$ converging pointwise to 0 as $k \rightarrow \infty$, so that one has
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathcal{H}}f_k
d\widetilde{\mu}_n=0$$ for all $n$. My question is: is this convergence uniform in $n$?
